# Multiple items in array causing TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, mongodb, simplejson

I have the following snippet from a script that grabs a zipcode from an array, grabs a url with that zipcode, and uses simplejson to parse and load it into mongodb.

```
zipcodes = ['10005']

for z in zipcodes:
    r = requests.get('example.org/zipcode/not-the-real-url')
    rj = simplejson.loads(r.content)

    for doc in rj:
        groupcoll.insert(doc)
        grouplist.append(doc['urlname'])
```

It works as expected with just one item in the zipcodes array, but when I add a second item, i.e.,

```
zipcodes = ['10005', '20005']
```

And change nothing else, here's the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "meetup_description_analyze.py", line 28, in <module>
    groupcoll.insert(doc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2212, in insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 583, in _insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.__write_response_codec_options, bwc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/message.py", line 770, in _do_batched_write_command
    for doc in docs:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 551, in gen
    doc['_id'] = ObjectId()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

What am I overlooking? I'm no expert (obvs.) but I thought this was good and I'm at the end of my troubleshooting ability. TIA.

Comment: Does this happen for any second zipcode?   Have you tried to put a ```try/except``` block around the lines and print out the objects/variables in the except suite?  Now may be a good time to delve into and get familiar with [The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) it can be more useful than pulling your hair out.